# Hide other users visibility

Tags: profile, sharing, user, visibility

I would like to know if it is possible to hide the visibility of all users to a specific profile. In particular, our need is to list only a certain type of users in the calendar multi-users view and in general in the org.

I have tried by removing the flags 'Manage users', 'View setup and configuration', 'View all data' and 'Manage internal users' for my profile but it did not work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to be honest I've never done this and can't comment on any unintended side effects (check in a sandbox!) but you can set the sharing setting of the user object to private in the normal manner:
Setup > Security Controls > Sharing Settings

[image]

Comment: Oh my! I feel so stupid, i've looked for UserS and did not find this under sharing settings. Thanks!

Comment: No worries, easily done.